# Matching a character twice in a list command with regexp: why does this match?

Tags: regex, bash, glob

I wanted to match the sequence job_ + two numbers + .sh so I used this regexp: `ls job_[0-9]{2,}.sh`

However the result is:

```
job_0.sh   job_1.sh   job_2.sh   job_3.sh   job_4.sh   job_5.sh
job_6.sh   ob_7.sh   job_8.sh   job_9.sh job_12.sh  job_22.sh
job_32.sh  job_42.sh job_52.sh  job_62.sh  job_72.sh  job_82.sh  job_92.sh
```

Somehow the regexp return also:  job_ + one number + .sh

Is this a bug or I am missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell glob pattern is not regex hence `{2,}` doesn't work. You can use:

```
ls job_[0-9][0-9].sh
```

Shell glob pattern expands `job_[0-9]{2,}.sh` to:

- literal `job_`
- A digit `0-9`
- **A digit** `2`
- literal `.sh`

That is the reason why you're getting all the filenames with `2` just before `.sh`

Comment: Oh I see. So in addition to what you said, {2,} is probably expended like 'a digit or nothing' that's why I probably also get job_0.sh job_1.sh and so on.